# Accessing a parent's model attributes from child model in django

Tags: python, django

please can anyone help me out am stuck i want to access items in the **item** model which i have referenced in the **OrderItem** model but am trying to access the item from Order model
here are the models
here is the model that am using to access

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey('Address',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='shipping_address',blank=True,null=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey('Payment',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    being_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_requested = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_granted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the parent model which i want to access

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered_order = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

and the item am trying to access must in this model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, related_name='itemTags')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    size = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=5)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    image = models.ImageField()
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    Display = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,
                                  decimal_places=1,
                                  blank=True,
                                  null=True)
    ram = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    hdd = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    lens = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

i was trying with this but seem not to work

```
recent_orders=Order.objects.filter(user=2)
 for item in recent_orders:
     print(item.items.item.title)
```

can anyone help me out Please!!!

Comment: can you please give us more information about your problem? It is very vague as is.

Comment: am trying to access item which is the product model ,but am doing it from Order model which reference OrderItem model which also reference Item model so i want to pass through Order to get the Items since am referencing OrderItem which references the item model

Answer (score 0):

You need thi code:

```
recent_orders=Order.objects.filter(user=2)
for order in recent_orders:
    for order_item in order.items:
        print(order_item.item.title)
```

try to give different names to all your variables, this will make programming more effective